# Is there a performance difference between `dedupe.match(generator=True)` and `dedupe.matchBlocks()` for large datasets?

Tags: python-dedupe

I'm preparing to run dedupe on a fairly large dataset (400,000 rows) with Python. In the documentation for the `DedupeMatching` class, there are both the `match` and `matchBlocks` functions. For `match` the docs [suggest to only use on small to moderately sized datasets](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe/blob/master/dedupe/api.py#L192). From looking through the code, I can't gather how [`matchBlocks`](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe/blob/master/dedupe/api.py#L96) in tandem with [`block_data`](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe/blob/master/dedupe/api.py#L265) performs better than just `match` on larger datasets when the `generator=True` in match.

I've tried running both methods on a small-ish dataset (10,000 entities) and didn't notice a difference.

```
data_d = {'id1': {'name': 'George Bush', 'address': '123 main st.'}
         {'id2': {'name': 'Bill Clinton', 'address': '1600 pennsylvania ave.'}... 
         {id10000...}}
```

then either method A:

```
blocks = deduper._blockData(data_d)
clustered_dupes = deduper.matchBlocks(blocks, threshold=threshold)
```

or method B

```
clustered_dupes = deduper.match(blocks, threshold=threshold, generator=True)
```

(Then the computationally intensive part is running a `for-loop` on the `clustered_dupes` object.

```
cluster_membership = {}
for (cluster_id, cluster) in enumerate(clustered_dupes):
    # Do something with each cluster_id like below
    cluster_membership[cluster_id] = cluster
```

I expect/wonder if there is a performance difference. If so, could you point me to the code that shows that and explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no difference between calling `_blockData` and then `matchBlocks` versus just `match`. Indeed if you look at the code, you'll see that `match` calls those two methods.

The reason why `matchBlocks` is exposed is that `_blockData` can take a lot of memory, and you may want to generate the blocks another way, such as taking advantage of a relational database.

Comment: Thanks! That makes perfect sense. I didn't think of generating blocks another way.